# sudo mysqldump : Permission denied

Tags: users, privileges

I am trying to run

```
sudo mysqldump
```

with user account but I get : `Permission denied` message

If I switch to `sudo su` then it works.

The question is why `sudo` gives permission denied? should i give some other privileges on my user account?

Comment: The problem is that if i login with root user i can take a mysqldump without problem.
But if i login with user account i get permission denied and i must run sudo su first.

Comment: That is because even though sudo gives you elevated privileges it doesn't change the user that you are trying to access the db with. Meaning if you are trying it with sudo mysqldump it is still trying it with your user but with elevated permissions, but with sudo su you become root - a user which exists in the DB by default - which makes it work.

Answer (score 17):

`mysqldump` on a production server does not work with sudo. Please try this:

```
$ sudo su
# mysqldump database> database.sql
```

Comment: wow great. thakssssssssssssssssssssss a lot

Comment: Woah, can't believe but it was that straight!

Answer (score 5):

Try to save dump into user home directory

e.g. `mysqldump -u {db_user} -p --databases {db_name} > /home/{user}/my.dump.sql`

Answer (score 3):

`mysqldump` will need a password for the mysql user root. If you don't supply that password it won't work, `sudo` or no sudo.

`mysqldump` can look at your `.my.cnf` file to get the password, and it'll get that from the user runing the `mysqldump` command. So, if the Linux root user has a `.my.cnf` configured with a password in it, then yes, sudo will help. However, if the mysql root user has a password and it's not configured in any .my.cnf's then sudo won't help.

You could add the mysql root user and password to your own user's `.my.cnf` and then you don't need sudo either, but that's a security risk.

As the other answers point out as well, you might need sudo to write the output somewhere that root (Linux, not mysql) owns.

Lastly, you don't tell us which user is executing the script, if it's in root's crontab (for example), then sudo will not be necessary, although you may still need a `.my.cnf` to provide the password.

If your mysql root user has no password set, then the only issue is writing the output, in which case sudo is required if you don't run the script as root.

If you run the script as root (for example, as a script in `/etc/cron.daily`) then you should not use sudo within the script, irrespective of all the above

[credit](http://www.faultserver.com/q/answers-do-i-need-to-add-sudo-for-mysqldump-command-for-the-mysql-backup-script-387072.html)

Answer (score 3):

This did work for me:

```
mysqldump -u {db_user} -p --databases {db_name} > /home/$USER/my.dump.sql
```

Comment: this worked for me, very thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Add write permissions of the folder you want to dump the sql file in:

`sudo chmod 755 folder_url`

and run:

`mysqldump -u user -p db_name > db_dump.sql`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you command destination path mentioned.

For eg: `sudo mysql -u YourUsername -p DatabaseName > ~/Path/Where/you/Want/The/Dump/FiletoBe/Kept/dumpfile.sql`

Answer (score 0):

mysqldump requires username of the current user else it will take root as default. When you do aisi su, you automatically provide root access. Try this with your username in place of user. `mysqldump -u user -p` Enter password when prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Dump to your home directory was the better answer here for me. If, for example, you can't sudo and you get permission denied, it's actually denying you permission to write the dump to your current directory. Specifying your home directory will solve it.

```
mysqldump -u me -p --databases my_db > $HOME/mysqldump.sql
```